# docker: open /.env: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, jenkins-cli

### Goal

**Action:** Run command from my local machine

**Result:** Docker image deployed on cloud instance

### Approach

For remote deployment, I am using gcloud commands.

The command below is working but the only problem is that it is not picking environment variables file i.e. .env. I have this .env file placed in the working directory.

**Command:**

`gcloud beta compute ssh --quiet --zone "us-west1-b" "devop-beta-persistent-2" --project "my-project" --command 'sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 -p 50000:50000 -v ~/jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home -v $FILE_PATH/jenkins.yaml:/var/configurations/jenkins_casc.yml --name jenkins-devkit --env-file $PWD/.env $JENKINS_IMAGE:latest'`

**Error:** docker: open /.env: no such file or directory.

### What I already tried

I have tried setting path to:

- .env
- /full/path/to/.env
- $PWD/.env

but still getting the same error.

If I run this command on my local machine, it works fine i.e. picking up the .env file.

sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 -p 50000:50000 -v ~/jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home -v $FILES_PATH/jenkins.yaml:/var/configurations/jenkins_casc.yml --name jenkins-devkit --env-file $PWD/.env $JENKINS_IMAGE:latest

Can any one suggest the possible solution?

Comment: Your `$PWD` will be resolving to the PWD on your host and not inside your container. That is why it is not working. Use the container path to `.env` file

Comment: The file is placed on my host machine and i have tried opening file using "vi $PWD/.env" and I can access it.
Aren't we supposed to give the path of .env with respect to host?

Comment: That you will have to share inside the container using `-v` like you did for `jenkins.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

`touch .env.dev` fixed this error for me.
touch is a unix command line program that creates a file. In my case .env.dev was missing. I created the file using touch. I created the file in the folder where I run my docker file.